# How to compose portion of letter recurrence in this code of C ++ will work?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, ascii

You can see here that the code has three parts. The primary portion and the moment portion inquired me to discover out the line and word number which I did. But when I call the third portion (i.e. letter_frequency function) that portion doesn't appear in the console. I looked at numerous places but did not discover a reply. I would have profited in case anybody may if it's not too much trouble reply.

**Expected Output :**

Enter Your String :
Hey Lisa

how are you doing#

The input has 2 lines, 7 words, and the following letter frequencies :
A:2 B:0 C:0 ...like this

**Output Now :**

Enter Your String :
Hey Lisa

how are you doing#

The input has 2 lines, 7 words, and the following letter frequencies :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<math.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
void letter_frequency(char le[]);

    int main()
    {
        char str[400] = " ";
        int words = 1;
        int lines = 1;

        cout << "Enter Your String : ";
        cin.get(*str);

        while (*str != '#')
        {
            cin.get(*str);
            if (*str == ' ' || *str == '\n')
                words++;
            if (*str == '\n')
                lines++;
        }

        cout << "The input has " << lines << " lines, " << words
            << " words," << " and the following letter frequencies : \n";
        letter_frequency(str);

        return 0;
    }

    void letter_frequency(char le[])
    {
        //for Capitals
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 65; i <= 95; i++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(le); j++)
            {
                if ( (int)le[j] == i)
                {
                    sum = sum + 1;
                }
            }

            if (sum > 0)
            {
                cout << (char)i << ": " << sum << "\t" << endl;
            }
        }
        //For Small
        for (int i = 97; i <= 122; i++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(le); j++)
            {
                if ( (int)le[j] == i)
                {
                    sum = sum + 1;
                }
            }

            if (sum > 0)
            {
                cout << (char)i << ": " << sum << "\t" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are your `#include`s? Please show a [mcve] and a simple example of input and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: Looks to me like you're getting 1 character at a time, constantly overwriting the previous one with the current one; it's always being output to `str[0]`.  `letter_frequency` therefore only has the last character input to process, which would be a `#` which falls outside the ASCII range you're checking for, so it won't print anything.

Comment: BTW: you're using C++, so is there any reason you're using raw `char` arrays instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes I was told in my problem to use ```char``` and wait a bit for ```#includes``` and input and expected output

Comment: @Den-Jason I get your points slightly. But I don't know how can I solve it. I am just learning and a beginner. I mean how can I put the inputs into the function ```letter_frequency``` I can't figure it out

Comment: You need to read to a `current_position` `char*` which is initally set equal to `str`, `cin` to `current_position` and increment it after every `cin`

Comment: @Dhruva-404 at which point you are talking about?

Comment: while (*str != '#') this loop here.@SheikhAraf

Answer (score 1):

First, unless you are forced to use raw `char` arrays by your professor as a learning exercise, you should certainly be using `std::string` instead.

Second, without digging too much into whether the code actually does what it promises, the main error I suspect you are encountering is in your for loops:

```cpp
for(int j=0; j<sizeof(le); j++)
```

The problem is that `le` is of type `char[]`, which has no size baked into it and is another way of saying `char*`. Thus your use of the `sizeof` operator is really returning the size of a `char*` which is probably always 4 or 8, depending on your target architecture. What you need to do is either:

1. Use `std::string` and then call the `length()` function (preferred option).
2. Pass the size in with the string, e.g., make the signature: `void letter_frequency(const char le[], const std::size_t len)` and then pass the value as the second param. (`const` added since you don't want to modify those params within the function. The compiler can help you avoid mistakes.)
3. Compute the size inside the function by calling `std::strlen()` or similar.
4. Accept a known size: `void letter_frequency(const char le[400])`
5. Use a template to deduce the size, and then your `sizeof` statements will work:

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
void letter_count( const char (&le)[N] )
```

Comment: I attempted your 1,4 alternative to work with however all I get was a similar yield result. Possibly I can't sort out the information which should have been inside the '''letter_frequency''' and sorry for not understanding the 2,3,5 choice you gave

Comment: Again, I did not check your logic for other problems. In my attempt to build and run the adjusted code with an online compiler never finished, suggesting you have other problems. I was only answering what I saw was a specific flaw related to your use of the language -- viz., your use of `sizeof`. Regarding the other answers, feel free to ask questions, but #2 should be straightforward to implement: just replace your usage of `sizeof` with `strlen`. It won't be efficient as written because you need, but it will at least loop the number of times you intended and is simple to implement.

Comment: Anyway, much obliged for giving me that I can utilize the string. I may reevaluate this issue or I don't have a clue